# HTML Form Posts - Using Checkboxes with a Long Name attribute

Tags: html, forms, checkbox

I'm having a bit of an issue with some coding.  I have made a file restore PHP script that will allow a person to place a checkbox next to the name of a file - and then when they click the "Restore" button at the bottom, it will restore the file in question from a backup.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem.  The full path and name of the file are in the checkbox's "name" attribute - so that way it is passed along to the next script as the location and file that needs restored.

As an example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="/backups/Sunday/111111111111-com/www/components/com_virtuemart/" />
```

See how long the "name" attribute is?  In many cases, the restore works - but once the name attribute gets longer, it doesn't work anymore.  In the above attribute, the "name" field is 63 characters long.

Now, if another one is tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="/backups/Sunday/111111111111-com/www/components/com_virtuemart/js/" />
```

The above "name" attribute is 67 characters long.  It DOES NOT work.

On the script that the POST data is being posted to, I did a var_dump($_POST); to see what the output was.  In the first case where the "name" attribute was 63 characters long, the var_dump displays it.  But in the second case where the attribute was 67 characters long, it does not display it - and therefore the file is not restored.

Is there any way around this supposed attribute size limit?  I looked online and saw several posts where individuals said there was no limit to the length of the "name" attribute - but apparently there is one.

Thank you!

Comment: OK - I think I have discovered my own issue here.

PHP is installed with the suhosin module.  I disable the suhosin module and it seems to be working fine.

Now I just need to figure out which setting to change in the module to allow for the long names.

Comment: Problem has been RESOLVED.  Cause was Suhosin module in PHP. I had to modify the suhosin.post.max_name_length from the default 64 and also had to modify the suhosin.request.max_varname_length from the default 64.  Modifying only one of these didn't cause the problem; both had to be changed from the default.

Comment: suhosin.post.max_name_length is what you want i believe. You will also want to change the corresponding "request" version of this config variable too

Comment: You just keep beating me to it every time. Glad you sorted it !

Answer (score 0):

Its the suhosin php hardener thats doing it no doubt. You can either edit the suhosin config directory or you need to take a different approach.

Maybe the easiest way without recoding a chunk of your script to use aliasing or storing a key=>value array persistently would be to simply make the name of your inputs "files[]" and put the path tot he file as the checkbox value. then you can just do

```
foreach($_POST['files'] as $f) {
 //$f is the file path
}
```

However myself i dont like to do things like this. Id try and store a key=>value array somewhere. If you dont want to use a database, just serialize a php array into a file, then just have the checkboxes with the integer array key for each file. Then on the processing script you can simply get the files from the stored array at the posted integer indexes